# no matter what I do my code would result the same

Tags: php, html

I wonder why I am getting the result as 4

```
<?php
function minusNum($aNum){
    $result=$aNum-1;
    return $result;
}

$theNum=4;
minusNum($theNum);
echo $theNum;
?>
```

Comment: You're not using the data your function is returning. It should be `$theNum = minusNum($theNum);`

Comment: .... or pass by reference: `minusNum(&$aNum) {$aNum = $aNum - 1); }`

Answer (score 2):

Your `minusNum` function returns a new value, it doesn't manipulate the inputted `$aNum`. You should use that returned value. E.g.:

```
$result = minusNum($theNum);
echo $result;
```

Comment: i didn't quiet understand .. maybe give me a correction and I will get it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the result from your function.

```
  <?php

  function minusNum($aNum){
      $result = $aNum - 1;
      return $result;
  }

  $theNum = 4;

  $theNum = minusNum($theNum); 

  echo $theNum;
 ?>
```

Here you assign the result of the function back to your original variable `$theNum`.

Although you pass the variable into the function, it is only altered inside the function. The value remains the same outside of the function.

Comment: I am very sorry .. maybe studying java before and learning that a variable would be changed if you apply a statement to it without assigning it every time .. I mean in java this my original code would work .. doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe if you pass it into the function as a reference. PHP only passes objects by reference by default, everything else is by value. If you want to pass scalars or arrays by reference, to need to indicate that on the function by prefixing the function argument with `&`, e.g. `function minusNum(&$aNum) {}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function minusNum($aNum){
    $result=$aNum-1;
    return $result;
}

$theNum=4;
echo minusNum($theNum);
?>
```

Echo the function because it returns result
   but when you echo $theNum you will get the $theNum value which is 4.
   Moreover the function will grape the value of any value variable that passes through not the variable it self. so you contradicting youself. I hope it helps.